# Apache Beam: Trigger for Fixed Window

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

According to [following](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Window.html) documentation, it is stated that if you don't explicitly specify a trigger you get behavior described below:

> If unspecified, the default behavior is to trigger first when the
> watermark passes the end of the window, and then trigger again every
> time there is late arriving data.

Is this behavior true for FixedWindow as well? For example you would assume fixed window should have a default trigger of repeatedly firing after watermark passes end of window, and discard all late data unless late data is explicitly handled. Also where in the source code can I see definition of trigger for, example FixedWindow object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best doc to start with is the guide for [triggers](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers), and [windows](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing-basics) (and following the links from there). In particular, it says that, even though the default trigger fires every time late data arrives, in default configuration it still effectively only triggers once, discarding the late data:

> if you are using both the default windowing configuration and the
>   default trigger, the default trigger emits exactly once, and late data
>   is discarded. This is because the default windowing configuration has
>   an allowed lateness value of 0. See the Handling Late Data section for
>   information about modifying this behavior.

**Details**

Windowing concept in Beam in general encompasses few things, including assigning windows, handling triggers, handling late data and few other things. However these things are assigned and handled separately. It gets confusing quickly from here.

How the elements are assigned to a window is handled by a `WindowFn`, [see here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/279a05604b83a54e8e5a79e13d8761f94841f326/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/WindowFn.java#L62). For example `FixedWindows`: [link](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/279a05604b83a54e8e5a79e13d8761f94841f326/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/FixedWindows.java#L73). It is basically the only thing that happens there (almost). Assigning a window is a special case of grouping the elements based on the event timestamps (kinda). You can think of the logic being similar to manually assigning custom keys to elements based on the timestamps, and then applying `GroupByKey`.

Triggering is a related but separate concept. Triggers are (roughly) just predicates to indicate when the runner is allowed to emit the data accumulated in the window so far ([source](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/279a05604b83a54e8e5a79e13d8761f94841f326/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/Trigger.java#L135)). I think this is the closest thing to the original design doc for triggers: https://s.apache.org/beam-triggers

Lateness is another related part of the configuration which is also somewhat separate ([link](https://s.apache.org/beam-lateness)). Even though a trigger might allow the runner to emit all the late data forever, the pipeline can be set to not allow any late data (which is the default behavior), or only allow late data for some limited time. This leads to the default trigger behavior described above. Yes, this is confusing. Avoid using any complex triggering and lateness if you can, it likely won't work as you expect it to.

So the window classes only handle the grouping logic, i.e. what kind of elements have the same grouping key. These classes don't care about when you will want to emit the accumulated results. This depends on your business logic, e.g. you might want to handle newly arrived elements, or you might want to discard them, it's not part of the window. This means there's no special triggers for `FixedWindows` or other windows, you can use any trigger with any window (even if logically some specific trigger doesn't make sense in context of some window).

[Default trigger](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/279a05604b83a54e8e5a79e13d8761f94841f326/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/windowing/DefaultTrigger.java#L43) is just that, something that is just set by default. You should assign your own trigger if it doesn't suit your needs. And it likely won't, except for some basic use cases.

**Update**

[An example](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/828b897a2439437d483b1bd7f2a04871f077bde0/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/LeaderBoard.java#L259) of how to use `FixedWindows` with triggers.

Comment: So if you don't specify trigger at all and just the WindowFn, default trigger will be used. And default trigger states that it will fire for all the late data. I am confused. What is the the behavior if you don't set trigger at all? And where is this documented?

Comment: It is confusing, yes. If you don't specify the trigger, the default trigger is used, yes. And it does fire for all late data, yes. But by default allowed lateness is set to zero, so in reality there will be no late data reaching the trigger so it will actually fire only once. Unless you specify allowed lateness greater than zero.

Comment: The fact that default lateness of zero results in default firing only once is mentioned here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers

Comment: More about lateness is here: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#watermarks-and-late-data

Comment: And the example of how to set it is here: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/828b897a2439437d483b1bd7f2a04871f077bde0/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/LeaderBoard.java#L274

Comment: Basically, when you say `Window.into()`, only things that you explicitly specify are updated on the `PCollection`. If you don't specify the trigger, the previously specified is used (or default trigger if nothing was explicitly specified before). If you don't specify lateness, the previously specified value is used (or zero if nothing was explicitly set before).

Comment: The Apache Beam programming guide is extremely well written until you get to windows/triggers, and then it becomes hard to follow. If you have a trigger to fire after 18 seconds of processing time and fixed windows that are 60 seconds long, what happens? Is the pane sent to the next PCollection 3x per window? 4x (e.g. 3x for the trigger and once for the end of the window)? Something else? How do you know if the 18 second trigger repeats or is only invoked once?

Comment: Another thing that's kind of confusing: By dividing into windows you are already achieving the goal of processing smaller amounts of data rather than waiting for "all" of the data to be available (which of course might not be possible). So it isn't clear to me why you would need triggers to get it even faster. If you wanted to get the data even faster, you could just make your windows smaller.

Comment: Windows are based on event-time in Beam. When you define a window it means something like "I want to group all the events that happened between 1pm and 2pm UTC 2019". So that all events will belong to that window no matter when they actually reached the pipeline (e.g. Dataflow server). Imagine you have a million mobile phones with slow connections and sometimes without connections at all. On those mobile phones you log when the users tap the button. And when you log it on the phone you use the phone's local timestamp.

Comment: Now if the phone immediately sends the event to the pipeline, it's roughly the same timestamp. But what if the phone goes offline for few hours? Then when you attempt to send an event the next time the phone becomes online the event will be few hours old. Sometimes it's ok to do it this way and ignore the timestamp of when the event actually happened. But if you want to account for when the user actually pressed the button, and not for when the event reached the server, then you need a concept of the event time space.

Comment: From the pipeline perspective it means that it should wait until all events for a specific window have arrived before actually doing the logic, e.g. calculating agg functions. If you're working in event time it means that it should wait for all late events as well. That is if the event from one mobile phone gets delayed for a few hours then the pipeline needs to wait until it arrives, and put it in the correct window, when the event actually happened, not when it was received by the pipeline few hours later.

Comment: But practically there is way to know when all late data has arrived. User can turn off the mobile phone for a year, and then a year later send when it comes online it will send the year-old events. In Beam's model these events will be accounted for in the old window that's a year old as well. Beam will see an event and say - hey, this belongs to that window from a year go, let me put it together with all the elements that we already received a year go.

Comment: So technically Beam cannot process any data until it knows that it has received all the latest elements for that window. Which means that it should wait forever in most cases since you don't know when the last late element can arrive. Which is not practical. So Beam has triggers to not wait forever. With triggers you say - let's actually process this window when trigger condition is met and not wait forever.

Comment: And when applying a trigger you also say what to do with late elements, e.g. you can say - "let's keep waiting for late elements for an hour, and re-run the whole logic for this window if a new element arrives, and if an element that belongs to that window arrives more than an hour later then let's drop it because we don't want to keep the old data forever and keep re-processing the old windows forever"