# How do default window and default trigger work in apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, windowing

I'm trying to implement the default window with the default trigger to evaluate the behavior but it's not emitting any result.

According to Apache Beam:

> The default trigger for a PCollection is based on event time, and
>   emits the results of the window when the Beam’s watermark passes the
>   end of the window, and then fires each time late data arrives.

---

> If you are using both the default windowing configuration and
>   the default trigger, the default trigger emits exactly once, and late
>   data is discarded. This is because the default windowing configuration
>   has an allowed lateness value of 0.

my code:

```
Nb_items = lines | beam.CombineGlobally(beam.combiners.CountCombineFn()).without_defaults() \
                 | 'print' >> beam.ParDo(PrintFn())
```

It only emits the data if I set a trigger

```
Nb_items = lines | 'window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.GlobalWindows(),
            trigger=trigger.AfterProcessingTime(10),
            accumulation_mode=trigger.AccumulationMode.DISCARDING) \
        | 'CountGlobally' >> beam.CombineGlobally(beam.combiners.CountCombineFn()).without_defaults() \
        | 'print' >> beam.ParDo(PrintFn())
```

How can I observe the default behavior without setting a trigger?

Is the problem in the combine transform?

> If your input PCollection
>   uses the default global windowing, the default behavior is to return a
>   PCollection containing one item. That item’s value comes from the
>   accumulator in the combine function that you specified when applying
>   Combine

Comment: Are you in stream processing ?

Comment: Yes, but at a certain moment I get all the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current issue is that the watermark never reaches the end of the `GlobalWindow`.  To have a default trigger, you can use any other window where the watermark can reach the end, e.g.: `'window' >> beam.WindowInto(window.FixedWindows(10))`

As Guillaume rightly asks, if you're running on Batch, triggers are basically ignored.

Comment: Another way to say this is that in Batch, the watermark eventually advances to +infinity, and the global window finishes, but in streaming the watermark generally has some resemblance to real time which never gets to +infinity.

Answer (score 0):

See Sources Below:

https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/828b897a2439437d483b1bd7f2a04871f077bde0/examples/java/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/examples/complete/game/LeaderBoard.java#L274

For more information regarding Google Cloud Dataflow

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54151029/12149235